# HTTP request with range

Tags: java, http, networking, network-programming, network-protocols

Hey guys my assignment consists in downloading a video file from a local server using http requests, i can already do that part , but they want me to download the video by segments, that means i my requests will be partial (i will not donwload the whole file with one request), the problem is that i'm always receveing the whole file. What am i doing wrong?

Significant part of the code:

```
socket = new Socket(server, port);
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
os.write(("GET /Lifted-" + "160" + "p.dat HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n").getBytes());
os.write(("Range: bytes="+Integer.toString(0)+"-"+Integer.toString((int) (bytedelay))).getBytes());
```

A sysoutprint of the range request:

```
Range: bytes=0-1089889
```

The header of the http response:

```
Last-Modified: Tue, 25 Nov 2014 15:08:03 GMT
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 05 Dec 2014 21:12:31 GMT
Server: Pygmy
Content-Length: 54518444 (whole file)
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say. One theory is that you're using HTTP/1.0, which predates range requests.